# How to check if a a new parameter was deleted in a method?

Tags: c#

```
public void test1(int noCD, EmpModel emp) {

}
```

I  already deleted the EmpModel parameter in test1 method but how to check if it exists or not for my UnitTesting

Comment: What do you mean with "exist"? If it not there your code will not compile. If you need a `null` check, just type `if (emp == null)`

Comment: Visual studio will not allow you to build if you're passing more arguments than the method allows for.

Comment: I already deleted the EmpModel as parameter, now I want to check if the method test1 has EmpModel as its parameter,is there a way to get all the parameters in a list of objects? then check it after 1 by 1?

Comment: aren't you talking about using `params` to check on the runtime if a parameter was passed or not?

Comment: yes that's it,my objective is to delete the EmpModel so I already deleted it,but the problem now is how will I UnitTest it?

Comment: Do one thing, start writing up the unit test and you'll see a red squiggly line when you call the method with that extra parameter and you'll know you did the job correctly. ok?

Comment: You could test this via reflection. But I don't see the purpose of the test. A unit test is to make sure something works as it should under certain conditions. If the method has no parameter you can't call it with that parameter. So a unit test makes no sense.

Comment: I 100% agree that this unit test makes no sense but nonetheless I must do it, do you guys have any way to get all parameters of a method then put it into a list or something so I can just check it 1by1 after?

Comment: @GerdK thanks for the reflection tip, I searched it and I think this is doable,ill just do that

Comment: @kenjirojaucian Please mark my answer as accepted if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved via reflection.

You can use [MethodInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo?view=netcore-3.1) to analyze the signature of method.